# LDAP: Error creating springSecurityFilterChain: AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-ldap

Here is my only configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true, jsr250Enabled=true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchBase("cn=users,cn=accounts")
                .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://1.2.3.4/dc=dev");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO: fix frontend
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I have no other configuration classes or annotations. My `application.properties` just sets the `server.port` and some logging levels. If I comment out the ldap code and use, for example, `inMemoryAuthentication`, then everything works fine.

I've tried every example of using `.ldapAuthentication()` online I can find, including some of the related questions here, and they all result in this error. What is wrong?

---

I believe all the relevant dependencies come from these lines:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

A small portion of the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:44)
    ...
```

Comment: Did you add `compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap" ` dependency?

Comment: Nope, that was the problem. Thanks! I eventually figured out it was building twice and the first time was failing because of a `NoClassDefFound org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry$RequestMatchers` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `compile org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap` will solve it as suggested by Ali.